# No application 'Dial' for extension error in Asterisk

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, asterisk

I have three extensions with extension no. `2000`,`2001`,`2002`.Separately i am able to call from one extension to another. While calling the any extension it getting error like this **No application 'Dial' for extension error in Asterisk**

My `sip.conf` like this

```
[general]
port = 5060
bindaddr = 0.0.0.0
context = others

[2000]
type=friend
context=demo
secret=1234
host=dynamic

[2001]
type=friend
context=demo
secret=1234
host=dynamic

[2002]
type=friend
context=demo
secret=1234
host=dynamic
```

and `extensions.conf`

```
[demo]
exten => 2000, 1, Dial (SIP/2000)
exten => 2000, 2, Voicemail (u2000)
exten => 500, 1,Answer()
exten => 500, 2, playback(demo-echo)
exten => 500, 3, Echo
exten => 500,5,Hangup

exten => 2001, 1, Dial (SIP/2001)
exten => 2001, 2, Voicemail (u2001)

exten => 2002, 1, Dial (SIP/2002)
exten => 2002, 2, Voicemail (u2002)
```

please help me how to resolve this issue.Thanks in advance

Comment: I think module app_dial.so is not loaded because of settings or errors.
In Asterisk CLI try: `module load app_dial.so` and write here what it says.

Comment: @AlexoPo. i executed like this. In CLI it shows like this `loader.c:908 load_resource:Module app_dial.so already exists`.

Answer (score 1):

Funny, but...

You said you got error 
**No application 'Dial' for extension (...)**
, but due to your dialplan (and due to what I have tried) you should have got
**No application 'Dial ' for extension (...)**

So, try this dialplan, where all unnecessary blanks are removed:

```
[demo]
exten => 2000, 1, Dial(SIP/2000)
exten => 2000, 2, Voicemail(u2000)
exten => 500, 1,Answer()
exten => 500, 2, playback(demo-echo)
exten => 500, 3, Echo
exten => 500,5,Hangup

exten => 2001, 1, Dial(SIP/2001)
exten => 2001, 2, Voicemail(u2001)

exten => 2002, 1, Dial(SIP/2002)
exten => 2002, 2, Voicemail(u2002)
```